Prevent asyncpg from processing output from postgres? (return raw data)
I am trying to return raw data, as in string / bytes, from a postgresql query executed with asyncpg, without asyncpg parsing the output data into a Record/dict. In my case I use a cursor, but I think the question is general.
Why?
I am returning pre-processed json data, ready for an endpoint. I do not want to parse this data, turn it into a dict, and then in python, re-encode it back as json. It seems like a lot of wasted effort. I am returning very much data, so I expect that preventing this will result in significantly increased performance.
My code is essentially this:
query = "SELECT ARRAY_AGG(JSON_STRIP_NULLS('my', 'data', 'from', (select array_agg(somewhere) from databasetable)))"
# Never mind the actual query. It is big, but returns many lines of json.
# eg:
# {"my": "data", "from": [1,2,3]}
# {"my": "data", "from": [1,2,4]}
# {"my": "data", "from": [1,2,5]}

async def my_generator():
  async with get_transaction_somehow() as conn: # type: asyncpg.Connection | asyncpg.pool.PoolConnectionProxy
    async for record in conn.cursor(query, my_data):
      yield record # Here I just want to spew out whatever asyncpg gets from postgres



I don't think that you can prevent asyncpg from wrapping returned rows in Record objects, however you can cast JSON(B) values to text in the query to prevent deserialisation.
SELECT some_json_value::text FROM tbl

In the specific case of asyncpg, JSON values will only be deserialised if a decoder has been set, so by default JSON values will be loaded as str, however such a configuration may be inconvenient as usually automatic (de)serialisation will be required at least some of the time.
Here's a complete demonstration script:
import asyncio
import json

import asyncpg


async def main():
    conn = await asyncpg.connect('postgresql:///test')
    await conn.set_type_codec(
        'jsonb', encoder=json.dumps, decoder=json.loads, schema='pg_catalog'
    )
    await conn.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t78449946""")
    await conn.execute(
        """
        CREATE TABLE t78449946 (
            c JSONB
        )
    """
    )

    # Insert a record into the created table.
    await conn.execute(
        """INSERT INTO t78449946 (c) VALUES($1)""",
        {},
    )

    row = await conn.fetchrow("""SELECT c FROM t78449946""")
    assert isinstance(row['c'], dict)

    row = await conn.fetchrow("""SELECT c::text FROM t78449946""")
    assert isinstance(row['c'], str)
    await conn.close()


asyncio.run(main())

